# Does adding START/END tokens improve classification performances when doing sentiment analysis with neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language

I wonder whether adding START/END tokens improves classification performances when doing sentiment analysis of the text (i.e., classifying the text into some sentiment classes, e.g. negative/neutral/positive) with neural networks.

For example, the input sentence `I like this movie` would be replaced by `<START>I like this movie <END>`.